# Installing packages within canopy venv

Tags: python, pip, enthought, canopy

I am looking into using [Canopy Express](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-s-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-) as an IDE. My understanding is that it uses a backport of `venv` from Python 3 to [manage user-generated virtual environments](https://support.enthought.com/entries/21802240-Use-venv-not-virtualenv-with-Canopy-Python), in addition to being [a virtual environment unto itself](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/faq.html#where-are-all-of-the-python-packages-in-my-user-python-environment). I just want to verify that within any virtual environments I create in Canopy, I will be able to install project-specific packages not included in the Express distribution using `easy_install`/`pip` as described [here](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-Python-from-the-command-line). That last link doesn't explicitly say that such package management works in a user-created virtual environment, hence my uncertainty.

Put simply, what I want is (assuming all my projects are 2.7-based) to install Canopy Express once and use it as my default Python. Then for various projects requiring packages that Express doesn't include, I can create separate virtual environments and install such packages on an as-needed basis.

If I can't do this, the other alternative I see is to install Canopy Express in `virtualenv` environments on an as-needed basis, and then to use those environment's `pip`s to install extra packages.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need to install `setuptools` and `pip` into your venv. If you use the `-s/--system-site-packages` option, you can inherit these from Canopy's installation (you may need to manually install the `pip` package using the package manager before making your venv). Appropriately-modified copies of the `easy_install` and `pip` scripts will be installed into your venv and will install into your venv's `site-packages`.

Comment: Awesome, just what I wanted to hear! I am waiting on delivery of a new laptop to install Canopy Express. I will accept the answer when I can verify. Thanks!

Comment: I found that in order to avoid permissions issues, I had to use the `-s` option (having previously installed `pip`/any given package) but then `easy_install pip` anyway in my activated venv, and from then on install any other package I wanted.